# SQL / How to sort values by their format

Tags: sql, date, format, ms-access-2010, case

I need to recognize which of several formats a date is in.  Example table:

[image: the table i need to work on]

On the screenshot (this is an example, but on reality there is 120K+ rows), 'DATEPRO' values can have three different styles :

- YYYY (lines 1 and 2)
- "FY"+YY/YY (line 3)
- "In" +" "+M+"m" (line 4)

**I would like to know if there is more than one year of difference between 'DATEPRO' and 'DATECON'**.

If DATE PRO is "FY"+YY/YY style, I would consider only the 2 last digits (YY) as a year

If DATE PRO is "In 3m" style it would be No for obvious reasons

If DATE PRO is "YYYY" style, it will be an easy substraction

*examples :*

- *"In 3m" would give automatically NO,*
- *"2002" against "01/01/2001" would give YES,*
- *"2002" against "01/01/2002" would give NO,*
- *"FY02/03" against "01/02/03" would give NO, and*
- *"FY03/04" against "01/01/05" would give YES*

I think I should use the CASE operator, but it seems to be only applicable to specific cases, and not to detect the format of a column.
My real problem is not the substraction part of the operation, but the recognition of the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer depends on your data containing *only* those formats you specify in your question, and that all years are at least 2000, which must be true if you're depending on the last two digits for `FY` formatted values.

You're on the right tract with `CASE` and you can use it to identify formats in a situation like this where you know what limited set of formats you have.  You can then use `CASE` to convert the mis-formatted values into what you need.  Like this:

```
select 
case 
    when left(DATEPRO,2) = 'FY' then concat('20', right(DATEPRO,2))
    when DATEPRO like '2___' then DATEPRO
    else null
    end
as DATEFIX
from your_table
```

The first check triggers if the first two characters are "FY".  The second check triggers if the value starts with "2" and is exactly four characters long.  The `else null` weeds out everything else.

However, your tags indicate you're working with MS Access, which doesn't support `CASE`.  Instead it entirely replaces it with `IIF`, which functions as a simplified `CASE`.  `IIF` only supports a statement with one if/else condition so you have to write nested `IFF` statements for something like this.  It's much harder to write and harder to read.  The equivalent code for an Access query would be:

```
select 
IIF(
    left(DATEPRO,2) = 'FY'
    ,'20' & right(DATEPRO,2)
    ,IIF(
        DATEPRO like '2###',
        DATEPRO,
        null)
    )
as DATEFIX
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Select 
    *,
    Not (Right(DatePro, 2) = Format(DateCon, "yy") Or Right(DatePro, 2) = "3m") As DateMatch
From
    YourTable
```